# Resumable.js: Persist file uploading between redirects and browser restarts

Tags: javascript, fileapi, resumablejs

Is it possible to make file uploads resumable after page redirect / browser restart through `Resumable.js` or any other Javascript API? (I seriously miss NPAPI here)

Comment: Why -1? Please explain.

Comment: I did not downvote, but I guess it's because this question can be answered by a simple `Yes.`. Also, redirect and browser restart are two quite different scenarios - with a redirect, it may be far simpler to not reload the top frame and instead only update content and URL (or use an iframe).

Comment: @phihag, can you please tell me how can I persist file upload between browser redirects on all browsers using *pure javascript*? I also tried to upload using a popup window, but still no luck with IE family (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34198760/javascript-persist-file-upload-between-redirects).